# How to disable an "anonymous" JTextField while adding it to a component?

Tags: java, swing

When you have a `JPanel`, you can add a `JTextField` in 2 ways:

**Way one:**

```
JTextField myTextField = new JTextField(10);
JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
myPanel.add(myTextField);
```

**Way two:**

```
JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
myPanel.add(new JTextField(10));
```

I do not know, how way two is called (anonymous `JTextField`, inner `JTextField`, ...?), so I did not find any information about it.

When using way two, I do not know, how to disable the `JTextField` while creating it:

`myPanel.add(new JTextField(10).setEnabled(false));`

is not working with the error `The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (void)`.

So is it possible to change the `JTextField` while creating / adding it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the anonymous class a non-static initializer and disable the field there:

```
myPanel.add(new JTextField(10) { 
    { setEnabled(false); }
});
```

Or if all has to be on one line:

```
myPanel.add(new JTextField(10) {{ setEnabled(false); }});
```

Comment: So `add(new JTextField())` indeed is called an `anonymous class`?

Comment: @hamena314: both of our codes use anonymous classes, yes. Our classes extend JTextField, but we aren't giving the classes any names.